# How to wait for asyncio.gather() results and then continue with the next line. (asyncio)

Tags: python, dataframe, python-asyncio, wait

im trying to do some http request async, and then append the results to a dataframe.
I'm having some trouble achieving this, first I tried using Asyncio.get_event_loop () and run_until_complete (), but it told me that there is already an event loop running.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import pandas as pd

async def get_page(page):    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:       
        async with session.get("https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000030/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=buy&page=1") as response:
            print("retrieving data of page: ".format(page))
            data = await response.read()                                    
            print("data retrieved of page: ".format(page))
            return data

async def get_orders():   
    pages = await asyncio.gather(*[get_page(page) for page in range(2)])
    return pages
                  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    var = loop.run_until_complete(get_orders())
```

> RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Then I tried to add a task to the loop that is running but I am not able to wait for the result before assigning it to the dataframe, rising a Result not set exception.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    task = asyncio.create_task(get_orders())
    var = task.result()
```

And finally I tried to create a global variable of the dataframe type, and fill it as my coroutine ran, but it seems that it is out of scope because nothing happens, my dataframe ends up empty.

```
async def get_orders(dataframe):   
    pages = await asyncio.gather(*[get_page(page) for page in range(2)])    
    dataframe = dataframe.append(pd.read_json(pages))
    return pages
                  

global df
df = pd.DataFrame()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    task = asyncio.create_task(get_orders(df))
```

> retrieving data of page: 1 data retrieved of page: 1 retrieving data
> of page: 0 data retrieved of page: 0
>
> df.shape Out[9]: (0, 0)

Well hope somebody help me, newbie here so any advice will be well received, thanks!

Comment: Your first attempt looks fine already, but you appear to be running this code through a Jupyter Notebook or something. Those interact weirdly with async code due to some [IPython changes](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/autoawait.html).

Comment: Yes I'm using Spyder with ipython.

Comment: @vergorabioso any feedback please?

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening a loop, it must be closed,
so after

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
var = loop.run_until_complete(get_orders())
```

Add this line

```
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `anyio` instead

```py
import aiohttp
import anyio  # pip install anyio
import pandas as pd


async def get_page(page):    
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:       
        async with session.get("https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000030/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=buy&page=1") as response:
            print("retrieving data of page: ".format(page))
            data = await response.read()                                    
            print("data retrieved of page: ".format(page))
            return data


async def gather(*coros):
    results = [None] * len(coros)

    async def runner(coro, i):
        results[i] = await coro

    async with anyio.create_task_group() as tg:
        for i, coro in enumerate(coros):
            tg.start_soon(runner, coro, i)
    return results


async def get_orders():
    pages = await gather(*[get_page(page) for page in range(2)])
    return pages
                  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    anyio.run(get_orders)
```